# Why mouse hover data disappear

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hover, mousehover

When I hover over element it show table in HTML code
but when I scroll, ad try again to hover, it does't work ? 
any help

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(0)
url = 'https://public.tableau.com/views/IRENA_Decentralised_RE_Data_Review_2019/ExploreData?:showVizHome=no'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

for i in range(10000):
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='tab-tvScrollY tvimages'][./div[@class='tvimagesContainer' and @style]]")
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = (0,{})'.format(str(i*49)),element)
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_by_offset(1330,200).perform()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: What data you want extract?

Comment: data that appears in HTML code when you hover, there appears table with country, plant/project name and etc.

Comment: @Kafels but I have another problem, this can not get data from columns People and Household, can you help me with this please ?

Comment: The "People and Household" data is covered in canvas, I've searched about extract data from it, but without success.

Other way it is exporting the table in PDF format and try use some libraries like `tabula-py`, `PyPDF2`, [...] to convert PDF to Dataframe

I did some tests using `tabula-py`, but wasn't totally success

Comment: @Kafels ok, I understand, I will try to find a way, but I think it can not be done. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spent three hours, I finally got it!

It's some Tableau behavior that `hover` doesn't work as well, can't say why.

Below it's my code explaining what I did to hover all lines.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(0)
url = 'https://public.tableau.com/views/IRENA_Decentralised_RE_Data_Review_2019/ExploreData?:showVizHome=no'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

scroll = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='tab-tvScrollY tvimages']"
                                      "[./div[@class='tvimagesContainer' and @style]]")
column = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//canvas[@class='tabCanvas tab-widget']")[1]

action = ActionChains(driver)
for i in range(10000):
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = (0,%s)' % str(i * 49), scroll)

    # Move cursor to hover element
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(column, 0, 0).perform()

    # Select HTML table
    table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='tab-tooltip tab-widget "
                                         "tab-tooltipBL tab-allowMouseEventPassthrough']")
    # Your selenium code to extract HTML content [...]

    # Move cursor to reset tableau hover function behavior
    action.move_to_element(scroll).perform()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, It reseolved my problem. The key was entering  action.move_to_element_with_offset